# In Therory: Best way to store SOAP results for filtering (PHP)?

Tags: php, json, search, soap

Trying to figure out the best way to handle this, but since I essentially work alone, i figured that SO community could help. Not looking for code, just ideas.

I am developing a web app for my company. Total rebuild. We are moving the product search from a database table we update nightly to a SOAP service that stores info for all devices in our industry (semiconductors). Personally I wish it were in the DB still, but the decision was made before I started, but anywho...

The SOAP publisher allows us to use essentially any parameter we would like about a product in the output, but restricts the input params to two, part # and manufacturer.

Long story short is they suggest taking the result set they provide and winnowing it down via search filters on our side.

Here is my (planned) approach:

1. make initial request via SOAP
2. if request returns 0, message user else continue
3. Take SOAP response (WILL BE LIMITED TO 150 RESULTS MAX) and
4. convert to json
5. Send json to view and use javascript/jquery to page and filter
6. If user has js disabled, display all results.

Alternate options involve using / filtering php arrays

I haven't done much beyond writing the small SOAP handler script. I now have results sets but am trying to figure how best to handle.

Comment: What kind of user interaction will you need to narrow the results down? Will you be able to do all of this in code, or will you require their input? I would personally recommend server side parsing if the user isn't necessary...takes out a lot of variables

Comment: a fairly common left sidebar/filter design pattern, either using controls or links. Will probablt be a "drill down" approach as opposed to parallel selection